# ¿Cómo puedo sumar un rango de valores de una columna de un dataframe en función de los datos de otra columna?

Tags: python, visual-studio, funciones, dataframe, sum

Tengo un dataframe en el que se encuentran una serie de datos con dos columnas. La primera columna tiene la forma nombredeusuario_numerodepregunta con un total de 18 preguntas por usuario y 30 usuarios en total. La segunda columna es la respuesta a la pregunta de los usuarios. Lo que quiero realizar es una función que me devuelva la suma de cuántas veces aparece la palabra 'eh' en las respuestas de cada usuario. Lo que no sé es como "filtrar" por nombre de usuario para que la suma sea por cada usuario.
Tengo esta parte de código:

```
df2_eh = df_pr['transcript'].str.count('eh')
print(df2_eh)
df2_eh_sum = sum(df2_eh)
print(df2_eh_sum)
```

La columna 'trancript' es las respuestas de los usuarios.
Pero esto solo me da el número de veces que aparece la palabra 'eh' en todo el documento y no separado por usuario.
Muchas gracias de antemano.

Adjunto la estructura del dataframe:

```
      id     transcript
0   jose_P1  Hola
1   jose_P2  Me llamo Jose
2   jose_P3  eh El tenis
3   jose_P4  eh Mañana
4   alex_P1  muy bien hola
5   alex_P2  eh a las 2 de la tarde
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para poder ofrecerte una solución lo primero es tener los datos.

Voy a escribir seguidamente un poco de código para generar un dataframe con esta estructura y con el número correcto de elementos. Para los nombres de usuario usaré `Nombre00`, `Nombre01` etc.. y para los números de pregunta `P00`,`P01`, etc. Las respuestas son palabras elegidas al azar de una lista, entre las que aparece la palabra "eh".

### Generación de un dataframe de muestra

```py
from itertools import product
from random import choice
import pandas as pd

palabras = "esto es una prueba con varias palabras para generar respuestas al azar eh eh".split()
def random_answer():
  return " ".join(choice(palabras) for i in range(10))

d = { "clave": [], "transcript": []}
for user, q in product(range(30), range(18)):
  d["id"].append(f"nombre{user:02d}_P{q:02d}")
  d["transcript"].append(random_answer())

df_pr = pd.DataFrame(d)
```

Esta es una muestra del dataframe `df_pr` que tiene en realidad 540 filas (30x18):

|  | id | transcript |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nombre00_P00 | esto eh al para con una al eh esto prueba |
| 1 | nombre00_P01 | prueba para una eh con palabras respuestas generar una al |
| 2 | nombre00_P02 | una eh es al prueba prueba con eh eh con |
| 3 | nombre00_P03 | generar al respuestas eh es es con generar para eh |
| 4 | nombre00_P04 | una para para palabras es eh una para respuestas generar |

### Solución a la pregunta

Lo que hay que hacer es crear una nueva columna que contenga solo el nombre, para así poder realizar después un `groupby()` en ella.

La siguiente líneas extraen el nombre de la columna `clave`, haciendo un `rsplit()` (split por la derecha) por el carácter _, pero deteniéndose en la primera división (`n=1`), por si acaso hay más caracteres `_` dentro del nombre. El nombre extraido se asigna a una nueva columna llamada `"Nombre"`:

```
df_pr["Nombre"] = df_pr.id.str.rsplit("_", n=1).str[0]
```

Seguidamente añadimos otra columna llamada `contador` que contenga el número de "eh" en cada fila:

```
df_pr["contador"] = df_pr.transcript.str.count('eh')
```

Ahora mismo el dataframe tendría esto:

|  | id | transcript | Nombre | contador |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 0 | nombre00_P00 | esto eh al para con una al eh esto prueba | nombre00 | 2 |
| 1 | nombre00_P01 | prueba para una eh con palabras respuestas generar una al | nombre00 | 1 |
| 2 | nombre00_P02 | una eh es al prueba prueba con eh eh con | nombre00 | 3 |
| 3 | nombre00_P03 | generar al respuestas eh es es con generar para eh | nombre00 | 2 |
| 4 | nombre00_P04 | una para para palabras es eh una para respuestas generar | nombre00 | 1 |

Ya sólo queda agrupar por nombre y aplicar `.sum()` a la columna `contador` de los grupos:

```
result = df_pr.groupby("Nombre").contador.sum()
print(result)
```

El resultado que sale (para mi ejemplo aleatorio) es:

```
Nombre
nombre00    30
nombre01    32
nombre02    20
nombre03    33
nombre04    31
nombre05    24
nombre06    19
nombre07    19
nombre08    18
nombre09    24
nombre10    28
nombre11    28
nombre12    25
nombre13    23
nombre14    24
nombre15    31
nombre16    28
nombre17    28
nombre18    26
nombre19    18
nombre20    24
nombre21    23
nombre22    22
nombre23    29
nombre24    33
nombre25    22
nombre26    28
nombre27    21
nombre28    23
nombre29    29
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por tu respuesta, me ha sido de gran ayuda. Un saludo! @abulafia